# How to associate RingCentral call data and Glip post data by user?

Tags: calllog, ringcentral, glip

How can I associate the call data from the RingCentral API to the user data in the Glip API.  As far as I can tell, the only overlap is the proper names located in the call logs `to` and `from` fields (which aren't always present), which can be mapped to an email address and then to a Glip user.  This seems like a very indirect way of going about things.  Are there ids or anything like that to link the two APIs?  Specifically I'd like to know if a call that's coming from or going to a person is also a Glip user in my organization.

**RingCentral Call Log API Example**

https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Call-Log-loadCompanyCallLog

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log

{
    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2018-11-09T07:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=100",
    "records": [
        {
            "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/call-log/abcdef0123456789?view=Simple",
            "id": "abcdef0123456789",
            "sessionId": "1234567890",
            "startTime": "2018-11-10T00:52:07.020Z",
            "duration": 11,
            "type": "Voice",
            "direction": "Inbound",
            "action": "Phone Call",
            "result": "Missed",
            "to": {
                "phoneNumber": "+16505550100"
            },
            "from": {
                "phoneNumber": "+12155550101",
                "location": "Philadelphia, PA"
            }
        },
```

**Glip Post API Example**

https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Posts-listGlipGroupPosts

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/glip/groups/{groupId}/posts

{
  "records":[
    {
      "id":"1542094852",
      "groupId":"155654",
      "type":"TextMessage",
      "text":"",
      "creatorId":"glip-29507587",
      "addedPersonIds":null,
      "creationTime":"2018-05-31T14:45:16.822Z",
      "lastModifiedTime":"2018-05-31T14:45:16.822Z",
      "attachments":null,
      "activity":null,
      "title":null,
      "iconUri":null,
      "iconEmoji":null,
      "mentions":null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is very strange to me.  I could have sworn I asked this question... not sure why my name's been removed.

Comment: There's a high probability that you did ask this question, but on Glip not Stack Overflow, which is why the question may seem familiar. The question was originally posted in Glip and I posted / paraphrased the Question with examples and my Answer here. You can search for this URL in Glip and find the quoted question and with my SO answer (Nov 10 UTC time, Nov 9 Pacific time).

Comment: Oh thanks. I was really confused; not trying to be confrontational

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are identified by the Call Log `extensionId` and the Glip `personId` which have the same value when the user is a company user.

- In the RingCentral Call Log API, each user is identified by an `extensionId`.

  - In the Company Call Log API (`/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/call-log`), you will receive call logs for all users and, to identify calls for each user, you need to query the detailed view by adding the `view=Detailed` query string parameter and then find the `extensionId` in the call `legs` array since multiple users can be present in a call. Each leg will have an `extension` property with a `extensionId` and HATEOAS `uri` property to retrieve information for the user.
  - In the User Call Log API (`/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/call-log`), the `extensionId` is explicitly stated in the URL path.
- In the Glip API, each user is identified by a `personId`. The `personId` appears as the `creatorId` and in other places in the Glip API.

  - When the Glip user is also a RingCentral user, the Glip `personId` value is the same as the `extensionId`, e.g. `12345678`
  - When the Glip user is a guest and not present in the RingCentral account, the Glip `personId` value is prefixed by `glip-`, e.g. `glip-12345678`

Here's an example of a detailed Company Call Log entry:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log?view=Detailed

{
  "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/call-log?view=Detailed&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2018-11-09T07:37:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=100",
  "records":[
    {
      "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/call-log/abcdef0123456789?view=Detailed",
      "id":"abcdef0123456789",
      "sessionId":"19923257004",
      "startTime":"2018-11-10T00:52:07.020Z",
      "duration":11,
      "type":"Voice",
      "direction":"Inbound",
      "action":"Phone Call",
      "result":"Missed",
      "to":{
        "phoneNumber":"+16505550100"
      },
      "from":{
        "phoneNumber":"+12155550101",
        "location":"Philadelphia, PA"
      },
      "transport":"PSTN",
      "lastModifiedTime":"2018-11-10T00:52:40.001Z",
      "billing":{
        "costIncluded":0,
        "costPurchased":0
      },
      "legs":[
        {
          "startTime":"2018-11-10T00:52:07.020Z",
          "duration":11,
          "type":"Voice",
          "direction":"Inbound",
          "action":"Phone Call",
          "result":"Missed",
          "to":{
            "phoneNumber":"+12675550100"
          },
          "from":{
            "phoneNumber":"+12155550101",
            "location":"Philadelphia, PA"
          },
          "transport":"PSTN",
          "billing":{
            "costIncluded":0,
            "costPurchased":0
          },
          "legType":"Accept",
          "master":true
        },
        {
          "startTime":"2018-11-10T00:52:07.050Z",
          "duration":11,
          "type":"Voice",
          "direction":"Inbound",
          "action":"Phone Call",
          "result":"Missed",
          "to":{
            "phoneNumber":"+12679304030",
            "name":"Sales Queue"
          },
          "from":{
            "phoneNumber":"+12155550101",
            "location":"Philadelphia, PA"
          },
          "extension":{
            "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222",
            "id":22222222
          },
          "transport":"PSTN",
          "legType":"Accept"
        },
        {
          "startTime":"2018-11-10T00:52:15.220Z",
          "duration":3,
          "type":"Voice",
          "direction":"Outbound",
          "action":"FindMe",
          "result":"Accepted",
          "to":{
            "phoneNumber":"+16505550100",
            "location":"Redwood City, CA"
          },
          "from":{
            "phoneNumber":"+12675550100",
            "name":"Tiger RingForce"
          },
          "extension":{
            "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/111111111/extension/33333333",
            "id":33333333
          },
          "transport":"PSTN",
          "legType":"FindMe"
        },
        {
          "startTime":"2018-11-10T00:52:15.257Z",
          "duration":3,
          "type":"Voice",
          "direction":"Outbound",
          "action":"FindMe",
          "result":"Accepted",
          "to":{
            "phoneNumber":"+18185550100",
            "location":"North Hollywood, CA"
          },
          "from":{
            "phoneNumber":"+12675550100",
            "name":"Tiger RingForce"
          },
          "extension":{
            "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/130709004/extension/130836004",
            "id":130836004
          },
          "transport":"PSTN",
          "legType":"FindMe"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To map to a Glip user, just map it to Glip users with the `personId` that matches the Call Log `extensionId`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I had overlooked the "extension" field in the documentation, but things are clearer now.